# How to free up memory when going from one scene to another in unity for ios devices?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

This is a game I am working on and it has a lot of textures(many). I am attaching some memory screenshots from Xcode.The scenario is like this first time opening app Home screen(scene 1-298Mb memory usage)>>Select first game (scene 2 -628Mb memory usage). In the same scene I am going to painting section suddenly the memory usage spikes to (scene 2 -1.01Gb memory usage). This is because lot of textures are used.After playing this I come back to Home scene still no change in memory. Now I play another game(Scene 3 -1.52Gb memory usage). It crashes when it reaches 1.81Gb.

No issues for android version as ram is higher for devices I guess.I am using addressables for downloading different scenes.Why the memory is not freeing up when we go from one scene to another.Tried unloading assets but still memory usage is the same.Any method to free up memory usage when we go from one scene to another?

[image: Home Scene]

[image: Scene1]

[image: Scene2]

[image: Scene2-Screen2]

[image: Scene3 -Crashing]

Comment: I believe unity never physically deallocates memory, but this doesn't necerarily mean you are running out. Unity keeps the memory it got from the system to itself, but internally frees it and is able to re-use it for other resources as needed, but it will not free it up for the system to give to another process. I might be wrong though

Comment: Other than crashing, have you confirmed if the RAM issues applies to Android too? You can take a look at Unity's Profiler to see the issue too: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html